# Zeep : Need to convert this sample soap request

Tags: python, soap, zeep

Soap Request :

```
<ws:credentialManagementRequestList> <ws:acspManagementRequestData>
<ws:credentialProvisioningStatus>ACTIVE</ws:credentialProvisioningStatus>
<ws:payload xsi:type="ws:OTPManagementRequest" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
</ws:acspManagementRequestData> </ws:credentialManagementRequestList>
```

complex type :

```
<xsd:complexType name="AcspManagementRequestData">
<xsd:annotation
<xsd:documentationThis type defines the Credential Management Request Payload</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:sequence
<xsd:element name="credentialProvisioningStatus" minOccurs="0" type="rsa_csd:CredentialProvisioningStatus" />
<xsd:element name="payload" minOccurs="0" type="rsa_csd:AcspManagementRequest" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Please help how to construct dictionary for ws:payload element

Dictionary Object created:

```
{'credentialManagementRequestList': { 'acspManagementRequestData': { 'payload': { '@type' : 'OTPManagementRequest' } } }}
```

Getting error:

```
TypeError: {http://ws.csd.rsa.com}AcspManagementRequest() got an unexpected keyword argument >'@type'. Signature: opcode: xsd:string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question :

Instead of parsing @type , I should get the type of OTPManagement object.

`"payload': { client.get_type('ns0:OTPManagementRequest') }`